# K- linear transformations and differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Given that $T_j : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ $j$ times $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $T_j$ is $j$-linear ,

and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ which is $k-1$ differentiable.

given that for $a,h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $f(a+h)-\sum \limits_{j=0}^{k} T_j (h,\cdots ,h) = o(||h||^k)$

Does this imply $f$ is $k$ differentiable ?

My attempt : let $g(a) = D^{k-1} f(a)$ since $f$ is $k-1$ differentiable, i want to show that $g$ is differentiable and from this $f$ is $k$ differentiable.

$g(a+h) = D^{k-1} f(a+h) = D^{k-1} (f(a)+Df(a)h +\cdots +\alpha(h))$ such that $\alpha(h) = o(||h||^k)$

here were i get stuck

any help for proceed or another proof would really help me.

Comment: Do you mean $f(a+h)\color{red}{-f(a)}-\sum \limits_{j=0}^{k} T_j (h,\cdots ,h) = o(\|h\|^k)$ instead?

Comment: @user1551 no since $T_0 =f(a)$ ,you could do that and start the sum from $j=1$ !